# Blender particle simulation as flow object source of fluid simulation simulation too violent or big in scale

Tags: particles, fluid-simulation

Ive got a fire simulation issue, the original fluid simulation I got looking fairly good and moving good (1):

[image]

But the fire was just moving up, I wanted it clumping into a ball and obviously force fields have little effect on a fluid domain so I remade it with a particle simulation which offers more control (2):

[image]

Now when I use the particle system as the flow source the whole fluid simulation literally explodes (3) like its scale is too high, set size under flow source is at its lowest (0.1) and I cant see a setting to reduce the fluid simulation scale like you can in Maya, only a time scale which has no effect:

[image]

The third screenshot is only 25 frames of simulation, something is obviously wrong but what. Does the amount of particles being emitted have any bearing? Everything is baked, particles, fluid domain (i haven't even had the chance to add in the noise bake yet due to this problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this. There were two factors at play:

1. There were too many particles being emitted, although their lifetimes were only 50 frames or so at 20K per hand it was too much. I lowered it to 1000 and it had an influence on the desired effect, I eventually settled on 5000 to maintain the flow of the connected fire streams coming from each hand.
2. The main factor was the fuel rate, at 10 on just the fluid domain was sufficient to get the look with the fluid domain ONLY, using particles as the emission object acted as a kind of multiplier to the original domain fire simulation. So setting the fuel rate back to 1 got the desired effect.